# How add FAB to bottom navigation bar with Compose in Material3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button, android-bottomnav, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Every tutorial or example of what I want to achieve uses `isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true` in a `Scaffold`. This is not present in Material3 Scaffold and I presume its part of what achieves the the bottom result

[image: Desired Nav Bar with FAB Look]

I cannot find any information on how to achieve this nor I see any control of the FAB except modifier.

I tried add padding and offset it , but it would not make the gap around it and the menu.

Comment: In the M3 guidelines there isn't a docked FAB in the BottomAppBar.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how would you show the fab so it is not hidden behind the M3 NavigationBar? Thanks!